# How does VHDL handle bitwise operations?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl

I'm having a problem in some VHDL code I'm writing. I want to drive a signal with two other signals AND'd together like this:

```
mysignal <= "010" and '1';
```

The result I expected was a bitwise AND, resulting in mysignal receiving the value of "010". Instead, I got a compiler error telling me "No feasible entries for infix operator "and"."  When I try:

```
mysignal <= "010" and "111";
```

it compiles. Is it possible in VHDL to do a bitwise logical operation, without having to alter my signals and make them all the same width?

Comment: Note that '1' is not actually "111" but rather "001". Which do you intend to achieve? Performing and AND with "111" or any vector of all ones is unnecessary since `A AND 1 = A`

Comment: Yes you're right I misspoke, ANDing with "111" would indeed be pointless. What I'm actually trying to do is implement a 2-1 multiplexer.  The 1-bit signal is the selector, and the inputs are 3-bit signals. I'm trying to use AND logic for the muxer.

Comment: you might want to look into using  when-else syntax that's usually used for muxing: `mysignal <= "010" when input = '1' else "000"`.

Comment: It needs to be combinatorial, so it's not taking place inside a process block

Comment: user3716057, that syntax is combinatorial, see here for examples: http://www.sigasi.com/content/signal-assignments-vhdl-withselect-whenelse-and-case

Comment: Oh interesting I though the WHEN keyword was only allowed inside a case statement, inside of a process block. This syntax makes my code much more readable, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to simplify generating signals of the right range. For example:

`mysignal <= "010" and (mysignal'range => '1');`

This creates a new value for the second operand, the correct size, with all bits set to '1',

Comment: I think I prefer this solution because it doesn't depend on the size of mysignal, making the code more portable. Thanks.

Comment: This does not make sense since `(mysignal'range => '1')` results in `"111"`, and a conjunction of `mysignal` with 1-bits does not change anything…

Comment: @aschipfl that's the operation in the question. I was only concerned with how to do it, not whether it made sense.

Answer (score 4):

In order to extend '1' to a vector of specific length,  usually I would use `(0 => '1', others => 0)` syntax.

for example:

```
 mysignal <= "010" and (0 => '1', mysignal'left downto mysignal'right+1 => '0');
```

This specifies that bit 0 is '1'  and the rest are zero, producing "001"

Another way is to concatenate the vector with zeros. I usually make a dummy signal called `zeros` as follows:

```
signal zeros : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)  -- or unsigned if you prefer
...
zeros <= (others => '0');
```

Then it's just a matter of concatenating the zeros vector with whatever other vector as you wish. The `&` symbols is the concatenation operator in VHDL:

```
newsignal <= zeros(newsignal'left downto newsignal'right+1) & '1';
```

If you want to concatenate another signal, then it's even easier:

```
newsignal <= zeors(newsignal'left downto oldsignal'left+1) & oldsignal;
```

This extends `oldsignal` to whatever length `newsignal` is. It won't work if `newsignal` is the same length or smaller than `oldsignal`. "010" becomes "000010", for example.

Note: Adding the dummy zeros vector doesn't change the size of your design in any way, the tools will optimise it out in any case and substitute it with all zeros. I just find it a lot easier to write `zeros` and select which range I want. naturally, you need to ensure that you zeros vector is as long as your longest signal. I find 32 bits works for most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
temp <= (others => '1');
mysignal <= "010" and temp;
```

where width of `temp` = 3.